# google maps click handler firing on page load

Tags: api, google-maps, events

I'm building a Google Maps app, and have an image of a compass outside of the map. Each of the compass points is on an image map, and has its own id. I want the 45° orientation to change, depending on the compass point clicked.

Within the google maps `initialize` function, I have this line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('compassSouth'), 'click', map.setHeading(180));
```

However, that handler is fired on page load, and doesn't respond after that. It's not due to the image map - the same behavior happens if the element is a button.

I have another handler in the same format that responds to a button press, which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do: It is calling the `map.setHeading(180)` function *immediately* when you execute your code.

Let's write it out line by line for clarity:

```
var element = document.getElementById('compassSouth');
var listener = map.setHeading( 180 );
google.maps.event.addDomListener( element, 'click', listener );
```

As you can see, this code calls `map.setHeading(180)` immediately where you write that code, and then it passes the *return value* from that function (which I'm now calling `listener`) into `addDomListener()`.

But `map.setHeading(180)` doesn't return any value at all - or put another way, it returns `undefined`, so `listener` is `undefined`.

`addDomListener()` sees that `undefined` value and ignores it: it doesn't set any listener at all!

What you need to do instead is pass a *reference* to a function into `addDomListener()`. You could do this easily like this:

```
function compassClick() {
    map.setHeading( 180 );
}

var element = document.getElementById('compassSouth');
google.maps.event.addDomListener( element, 'click', compassClick );
```

Or as you'll often see, you can make that `compassClick` function an anonymous function instead (now going back to code more like your original):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(
    document.getElementById('compassSouth'), 'click',
    function() {
        map.setHeading( 180 );
    }
);
```

Comment: Great, I'm glad that was helpful. I added a few more comments, mostly for future readers, since it sounds like you're on track now.